# Find a control style in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am setting certain controls using this

```
divCorporateId.Style.Add("Visibility", "hidden");
```

How do i check what the value is in another method?

I thought something like:

```
if (divCorporateId.Style........ == "hidden")
{
    do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Css property value in C# like this

```
string value = divCorporateId.Style["Key"]
```

then you can apply your conditions based on this value.

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
if (divCorporateId.Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.Visibility] == "hidden")
{
    do something
}
```

Comment: @Adam: If its working, you can accpet the answer by clicking the check mark on the left!!!